# Determining the initial conditions of a rotating/translating reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I am trying to derive a set of initial conditions consisting of a range (ρ), two angles (β and ε) and their derivatives. Calculating ρ β and ε was straightforward ;However, finding $\dot{\rho}$, $\dot{\beta}$ and $\dot{\epsilon}$ is a little tricky.

I am working with three different reference frames, the Inertial frame (I) (O, e<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>, e<sub>3</sub>), an intermediate frame A (O', a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>) and the final frame B (O', b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>). The transformation matrix from I to B is as follows:

\begin{equation}
R_{I \rightarrow A}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos(\beta) & \sin(\beta) & 0\\ 
-\sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) & 0\\
     0      &     0      & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
R_{A \rightarrow B} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos(-\epsilon) & 0 & -\sin(-\epsilon)\\ 
       0        & 1 &       0\\
 \sin(-\epsilon) & 0 & \cos(-\epsilon)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
R_{I \rightarrow B} = R_{A \rightarrow B}R_{I \rightarrow A}
\end{equation}

Now the dynamics can be expressed as follows:
\begin{equation}
r_{P/O} = r_{O'/O} + r_{P/O'}
\end{equation}

and with the help of the transport equation the velocity can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
(*) {^I}v_{P/O} = {^I}v_{O'/O} + {^B}v_{P/O'} + {^I}\omega{^B} \times r_{P/O'}
{}{}{}
\end{equation}

Through the derivation of the dynamics the angular velocity ${^I}\omega{^B}$ can be determined.

\begin{equation}
{^I}\omega{^A}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \ \ \ \ \ a_1 \\ 
 0 \ \ \ \ \ a_2  \\
 \dot{\beta} \ \ \ \ a_3 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{^A}\omega{^B}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\ \ \ \  0 \ \ \ \ \ b_1 \\ 
 -\dot{\epsilon} \ \ \ \ \   b_2  \\
\ \ \ \  0  \ \ \ \ b_3 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{^I}\omega{^B}
= {^I}\omega{^A} + {^A}\omega{^B}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{^I}\omega{^B}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \dot{\beta}\sin(\epsilon) \ \ \ \ \ b_1 \\ 
       -\dot\epsilon \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ b_2        \\
 \dot{\beta}\cos(\epsilon) \ \ \ \ b_3 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

This is where I get stuck, I know ${^I}v_{P/O}$, ${^I}v_{O'/O}$, $r_{P/O'}$, $r_{P/O}$, $r_{O'/O}$, $\rho$, $\beta$ and $\epsilon$. Another useful piece of information is that the way the frames are defined $r_{P/O'} = [\rho \ b_1; 0 \ b_2; 0 \ b_3]$ always. I'm stuck because I'm trying to solve for the unknown vector ${^B}v_{P/O'}$ in equation (*), which would be straightforward if I knew ${^I}\omega{^B}$, but I do not know $\dot{\beta}$ and $\dot{\epsilon}$. Currently, I have too many unknowns, being the 3x1 vector  ${^B}v_{P/O'}$, $\dot{\rho}$, $\dot{\beta}$ and $\dot{\epsilon}$; If I knew $\dot{\beta}$ and $\dot{\epsilon}$ I could calculate ${^I}\omega{^B}$ and consequently ${^B}v_{P/O'}$ which will give me $\dot{\rho}$ as ${^B}v_{P/O'} = [\dot{\rho} \ b_1; v2 \ b_2; v3 \ b_3]$.

I have the correct values of $\dot{\rho}$, $\dot{\beta}$ and $\dot{\epsilon}$ that I can use to check if the values I calculated are correct.

Comment: $\omega$ is a vector not matrix

Comment: $\omega$ is a vector, the b1/a1 are just the directions in the frame. I should have made that more clear

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Velocity in a turning reference frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame). **(2)** [Angular Velocity via Extrinsic Euler Angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672712/angular-velocity-via-extrinsic-euler-angles/672964#672964).