# $\left(\frac{d}{d t} \mathbf{L} \right)$ in a rotating coordinate system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, vectors

- We've a vector $\mathbf{A}$ lying in space and changing according to some rule.
- We introduce an inertial frame and find  $\left(\frac{d}{d t} 
   \mathbf{A}   \right)_{i n}$ in it.
- We also introduce a co located frame rotating with $\mathbf{\omega}$. In this rotating frame I find $\left(\frac{d}{d t} 
   \mathbf{A}   \right)_{rot}$
- There exists a relationship between the two time rates as
  $\left ( \frac{d\mathbf A}{dt} \right )_\text{inertial} = \left ( \frac{d\mathbf A}{dt} \right )_\text{rot} + \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf A$
- In all of this derivation it was assumed that the vector $\mathbf{A}$ was independent of the coordinate system. We merely observed the vector in two frames. The vector is independent of the coordinate system.

---

- Can we use the above equation on angular momentum vector $\mathbf{L}$ i.e $\left ( \frac{d\mathbf L}{dt} \right )_\text{inertial} = \left ( \frac{d\mathbf L}{dt} \right )_\text{rot} + \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf L$?

I think no we can't.

In the derivation of the $\left ( \frac{d\mathbf A}{dt} \right )_\text{inertial} = \left ( \frac{d\mathbf A}{dt} \right )_\text{rot} + \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf A$ we assumed that the vector $\mathbf{A}$ was independent of the coordinate system, its lengths and direction in space is independent of the coordinate system.

However for $\mathbf{L}$ that isn't the case.
$\mathbf{L}$ has a different length in a stationary frame than in a rotating one. So the derivation doesn't apply.

Comment: See this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBlCu1zgD4Y&list=PLMsYJgjgZE8hh6d6ia2dP1NI0BKNRXbiw&index=9&ab_channel=TheWE-HeraeusInternationalWinterSchoolonGravityandLight

Comment: Video is about curved space, how is that relevant here?

Comment: the video is for all spaces. If you want to foucs in flat sapces you use a flat connection

Comment: I sugest you to see the previous video as well the tutorial. it will open to you a whole new world

Comment: Related :  **(1)** [Velocity in a turning reference frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame). **(2)**  [Angular Velocity via Extrinsic Euler Angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672712/angular-velocity-via-extrinsic-euler-angles/672964#672964).

Comment: „ The vector is independent of the coordinate system.“ the magnitude of the vector is independent, but not the components of the vector?

Comment: @Kashmiri what is wrong with this answer ? 
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/678633/196140

$~\mathbf G\mapsto \mathbf L$