# Is angular velocity and angular acceleration independent of translating frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation, angular-velocity

[CONSIDERING ALL BODY RIGID]

So think of a body which is rotating if I see it from a rotating frame,let's say with same angular velocity then the body will appear rest to the frame , so will have zero angular velocity.

Now consider case of pure rolling of let's say a circular object (disc,ring,cylinder etc), now whether we see the angular velocity of the body with centre of mass frame (which is only translating) or the bottom most point frame(which is momentarily is at rest at that instant) , the angular velocity and angular acceleration is same.

So I was Just think is it true for all translating frame or if i see the body with any rotating frame or even the simultaneous rotating and translating particles of the body itself will see the body rotating with same angular acceleration and velocity and if yes then is it true for any other kind of frames too?

Or angular velocity and angular acceleration might not be same in frame of a body but rather it is same about every fixed axis and point at that particular instant?

Comment: Related : [Angular Velocity via Extrinsic Euler Angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672712/angular-velocity-via-extrinsic-euler-angles/672964#672964).